# SwiftUI .onTapGesture not being called from inside a foreach loop

Tags: swift, loops, swiftui

Here's the code that I am using:

```
var array = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y"]
HStack(){
    ForEach(0..<topRow.count, id: \.self){i in
        MyView(letter: self.array[i])
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Test")
            }
    }
}
```

All the "MyView"s are displaying correctly, but when I tap any of them nothing is printed. Also the MyViews are just a text().

Comment: Is `array` in your example meant to be `topRow`? If so, your code should work. If it doesn't, then something else (not shown in the question) is broken... i.e. the issue isn't reproducible with the code shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and solution. As New Dev pointed out, the error was being called by something not included in the code shown. I'll post what what wrong here anyways incase someone stumbles upon this.

What wasn't included was the code for MyView which I'll put here:

```
struct MyView: View {

    var letter:String
    @State var pressed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            if pressed{
                Text(letter)
                .font(Font.custom("ComicNeue-Bold", size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .opacity(0.23)
            } else if !pressed{
                Text(letter)
                .font(Font.custom("ComicNeue-Bold", size: 30))
                .foregroundColor(.white) 
            }
            
        }.padding(5)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.pressed = true
        }
    }
}
```

I solved the issue by removing the .onTapGesture from the ZStack. So I'm guessing that the issue is that views cannot have two .onTapGesture modifiers.

Comment: The first onTap intercepts the tap, which is not passed to the scond.